# "The location specified by MRJOB_CONF" in mrjob documentation

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-streaming, elastic-map-reduce, mrjob

Which path is "The location specified by MRJOB_CONF" in mrjob documentation?
Link to mrjob doc: http://mrjob.readthedocs.org/en/latest/guides/configs-basics.html

Answer (score 2):

This basically means that whenever MRJOB is setup in a machine, it will need to get itself initialized(set hadoop configurations for eg) to a set of values. These are actually the configurations one will setup and would have listed in a file named `mrjob.conf`. 
Now MRJOB will look for this file in following 2 locations:

- `~/.mrjob.conf`  (This actually is a hidden file created under the home folder of the user)
- `/etc/mrjob.conf`

Comment: Thanks Amar. I am having another prblm while trying to run MR jobs using mrjob on Amazon EMR. I am getting [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13949937/getting-socket-gaierror-errno-5-no-address-associated-with-hostname) error. DO you know how I can resolve it?